# Change input values of boxes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, input, html-table

I have a form that is being used to generate an email template.  At the bottom of the page I have a table that displays the email name, and which departments have access to use it.  Ultimately what I want to happen is make the name of the email at the bottom of the page to act like a button. When the user clicks on the email name, it will grab those values from the DB and pass them into the appropriate input field.  Below is a sample of my current PHP code.  If someone could provide a suggestion or even an example I would be grateful.

This is the form for the email template setup:

```
<form id="Email" name="Email" method='post' action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP']);?>">
<fieldset style="width: auto; height: auto;">
<legend class="legend1"><h2>&nbsp; Manage E-Mails &nbsp;</h2></legend>
<table width="100%" style="text-align:center">
<tr>
<td width="60%" style="text-align: left;">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Email Template Name" value="" maxlength="100" style="width: 250px; height: 20px;"/>
<input type="radio" name="from" id="from" value="user" />Send From User
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">
<input type="text" style="width:250px; height: 20px; visibility: hidden;" />
<input type="radio" name="from" id="from" value="department" />Send From Department
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">
<input type="text" id="To" name="To" placeholder="To: " value="" maxlength="250" style="width: 250px; height: 20px;"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="user" id="user" value="YES" />Autocopy User
<?php echo "&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;";?><input type = "checkbox" name="escalate" id="escalate" value="YES" />Make Escalated Email Only
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">
<input type="text" id="CC" name="CC" placeholder="CC: " value="" maxlength="100" style="width: 250px; height: 20px;"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="customer" id="customer" value="YES" />Autocopy Customer
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">
<input type="text" id="BCC" name="BCC" placeholder="BCC: " value="" maxlength="100" style="width: 250px; height: 20px;"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="additional" id="additional" value="YES" />Allow Additional Email Address(es)
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2 style="text-align: left;">
<input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject " value="" maxlength="100" style="width: 400px; height: 20px;"/> 
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('includes/adminpages/keywords.php', 'newwindow', 'width=500, height=400'); return false;">Keywords</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">
<textarea  name="content" maxlength="3000" cols="100" rows="12"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="float: left;">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

This is the form that allows users to update what department the email will belong to.  This where it will display the email name.  I want the email name to be clickable and to generate the info back into the table above.

```
<form id = "Display_Email" name="Display_Email" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP']);?>">
<?php
$get_business = mysql_query("SELECT bus_name, bus_id FROM business where bus_id = '{$_SESSION['bus_id']}'");
while(($business = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_business)))
{
echo '
<h3>'.$business['bus_name'].'</h3>
<table class="departments">
<tr>
<th scope="col" style="width: 175px;">Email Name</th>
';
$get_depts = mysql_query("SELECT dept_name FROM depts where bus_id = '{$_SESSION['bus_id']}'");
while(($department = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_depts)))
{
    echo '
    <th scope="col" style="width: 175px;">'.$department['dept_name'].'</th>
    ';
}
echo '
</tr>
';
$get_emails = mysql_query("SELECT id, email_name from emails where bus_id = '{$_SESSION['bus_id']}' ORDER BY email_name ASC");
while(($email = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_emails)))
{
    echo '
    <tr>
    <td>'.$email['email_name'].'</td>
    ';
    $get_depts = mysql_query("SELECT dept_name, dept_id FROM depts where bus_id = '{$_SESSION['bus_id']}'");
    while(($department = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_depts)))
    {
        $get_email_dept = mysql_query("SELECT dept_id from emails where id = '{$email['id']}'");
        while(($email_dept = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_email_dept)))
        {
            $departments = explode(",", $email_dept['dept_id']);
            if(in_array($department['dept_id'], $departments, TRUE))
            {
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="Email_Box[]" value="0">';
                echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="Email_Box[]" value="'.$department['dept_id'].'" checked="checked""></td>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="Email_Box[]" value="0">';
                echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="Email_Box[]" value="'.$department['dept_id'].'"></td>';
            }
        }
    }
    echo '
    </tr>
    ';
}
echo '
    </table>
    ';
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="Email_Submit" value="Submit" style="float: left;"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for. Because I could not read the whole question. Too long. Does your php file echo the right data? So you now want to know how to get that data dynamically or you have problem appending or modifying data in the form page?

Comment: @OptimusPrime I apologize for the question being too long.  Everything echos fine and displays fine.  The second form generates a table for the user where the left column shows all of the email template names.  All of the columns on the right have a checkbox in them where the user can select/deselect departments that can use the email template.  What I want is to make each email name clickable.  When they click the text, all of the boxes in the first form populate with the information originally submitted.

Comment: Sorry, it is to unclear what you want exactly. I guess you want to copy some information from the lower form to the upper form? This should happen on click? Maybe you can simplify your example?

Comment: @CBC_NS What problem are you facing here? You can use jQuery or javascript to do that. Are you not comfortable with javascript? Then I suppose this question has nothing to do with php? You need help with javascript only?

Comment: @OptimusPrime - Basically I need javascript only.  Let me try to explain this again.  The top form/table allows the user to input information for an email template, subject, content, etc.  The bottom form/table has a list of template names that have been created.  I want to be able to use javascript in a way that the user clicks on one of the template names at the bottom, it queries the database for that information, and repopulates the table.  That way the user can edit that information and save it again.

Comment: @CBC_NS Are you looking for [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)? I can help you with that, if you can make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).. ;)